# What versions of NumPy are compatible with Python 3.3?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

When I try to install any version of matplotlib I always get the following error when it tries to install NumPy

> RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.

Is there any way of getting around this?

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.3 was dropped with version 1.12.
Here is the changelog for this version: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/release.html

> Support for Python 2.6, 3.2, and 3.3 has been dropped.

The best way to get around this is definitely to move to a more recent version of python, as python 3.3 [is not maintained anymore](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398/#x-end-of-life).

If this is not an option, you can still use version 1.11.3 that you can download [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.11.3), or install it with:

```
pip install numpy==1.11.3
```

Comment: Well that's a nice condensed answer!